# <input type=number> validation error in IE11 (Windows 7, 8)

Tags: validation, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

`<input type=number>` on IE11 / Win7 and IE11 / Win8, given *min*, *max* and *step* does not accept some number ranges as correct with validation error "You must enter a valid value"

In my example, I've selected min as -90, max as 90 (geographical latitude input) with step 0.00001.

For some reason, following value ranges are invalid:

- 24 to 77
- -75 to -49
- -33 to -7

Gaps between those ranges are valid

Testcase with error: https://jsfiddle.net/w0r05kq7/4/

Code:

```
<form>
  <input type="number" min="-90" max="90" step="1.0e-05" value="58,69374">
  <input type="submit"></input>
</form>
```

This does not happen with Edge or IE11 / Win10

I'd like to keep using number inputs because of its usefulness on other browsers, but I need some IE support as well. Are there any workarounds or should I just give up?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with how constraints are being validated in IE. I tested with value 34, and on calling method `input.checkValidity`, it returns `false`. Also on checking `input.validity`, it shows `stepMismatch` error as true. It seems it has some issue while calculating these validations

I have made a plunker to replicate and funny thing is if you set your step size to 4 decimal places, then it work for all the cases but as you increase to 5 decimal places, it produces validation errors.

1. Plunker Link: http://plnkr.co/edit/kiy4t302ivwsDWb1C1vG?p=preview
2. Constraint Validation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5/Constraint_validation
3. IE11 issue: https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/850187/html5-constraint-validation-is-broken-in-ie11-for-input-type-number

I hope this will give you some idea about root of the issue. You can develop with 4 decima places if it is possible. I will look if there is any workaound for 5 decimal places with IE and will update answer if I find any one